# Recursively defined Object type - mapped type Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering if there is a built in way to define a type recursively. A simple enough way to do this that works for me is:

```
interface DeepTypedObject<T> {
    [key: string]: T | DeepTypedObject<T>
}

interface StyleSettings extends DeepTypedObject<string> { }

const example: StyleSettings = {
  styles: {
    primary: 'blue',
    secondary: 'red'
  }
}
```

Or to do so more in-line:

```
interface DeepTypedObject<T> {
    [key: string]: T | DeepTypedObject<T>
}

const example: DeepTypedObject<string>= {
  styles: {
    primary: 'blue',
    secondary: 'red'
  }
}
```

Feels like this is a very common use case and couldn't find  any other way to implement.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIQgBwCoE9MQAmA8gEYBWECYAPNgHzIDeAUMu8gNoDWEuAXMgDOYKKADmAXUHZkAHzQYc+ImUrU69FgF8WLUJFiIUAZTC4ANhBMQwYCUOQQAHpBCFH6LHgIkKVWhExEHFGJmRdFgQAexARJ2c4AFtMK0EzS2tbexDHAF5mNmFzKyFBVg5kTDEkuCgBZAByUgsAVwhGgBoi9iEqWMI6hsaoIkai3W0gA)

Comment: What do you mean "built in way", and how does what you did not work for you?  Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link)](https://tsplay.dev/w2Kp8N), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing, with no typos or undeclared variables or types. This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: The code did work, I'm just wondering if I really need to declare the DeepTypedObject interface manually to define types recursively, or is there actually a proper way to do this. The code works for me, as indicated in original question.

Comment: When I drop that code into an IDE there is at least one typo, which I’m asking you to fix. Plus you are referencing `CSSProperties` which is not declared or imported in that example, so you may want to remove the question’s dependency on it, or else define it, or tag the question with `react` or whatever framework brings it into scope.  You don’t have to declare an interface to make a recursive type; you don’t have to define `DeepTypedObject` to define `StyleSettings`; when I get a chance I can post an answer, but it would be best if the code in your question were a [mcve] first.

Comment: Updated the code example - didn't think it was needed to be run anywhere as I thought to use it just to explain how I do it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can define `StyleSettings` as an [`interface`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) directly, without reference to `DeepTypedObject`:

```
interface StyleSettings {
  [key: string]: CSSProperties | StyleSettings;
}
```

You could also write that as a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) instead, if you want:

```
type StyleSettings = {
  [key: string]: CSSProperties | StyleSettings
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYQMqoApQmAprYXAZzgF84AzbEOAcilwEMBjGWgbgChPgA7GfBRa44qGAE8ANrlS4YMPgHMSCTnDgBtANa5xALjhEYUJQF0DaTNjwFicAD6iJ02fKVEupbhLxOpMuQVeZQAVcV8AXkQ1TR19Q2MzC3QsHHwFO0cxf1cg0PDcTi9OZgheIzhcAA9GcGkDbJdA9zgo1XUjfyIDdvU4MBMQRih4pAAjFi1FbABXXgATA1oxyRncWjIAGhiO3FKF4dG4CeYp2YWlhnmNr3UvUiA)

Comment: That's along the lines what I'm looking for, thanks. I didn't know interfaces / types can reference themselves like this.
I don't suppose this can be used as an in-line declaration though?

Comment: "I don't suppose this can be used as an in-line declaration though?" If I understand correctly, no.  If you want an anoynmous type like `const foo: {[key: string]: CSSProperties | ...}` there's no name you can use to refer to the `...` part, which means you'd need to write out `{[key: string]: CSSProperties | {[key: string]: CSSProperties | {[key: string]: CSSProperties | ... }}}` which would be quite a lot of writing.  I can kind of imagine wanting a nonce recursive type, but without seeing a [mcve] of a use case that motivates it, my inclination is to say "just write a `type` for it".

Comment: Yes it's not too much work to do a `DeepTypedObject` as shown in the updated question code snippet. Just thought perhaps I didn't know how to do it properly because it looked a bit custom, when I expected perhaps something like the self referencing type would be available.